# I can't get a facebook app id even though I'm verified

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get a facebook app id for Oauth for a site I'm developing, and it tells me:

"Your account must be verified before you can take this action. Please verify your account by adding your mobile phone or credit card."

When I click on "mobile phone," it says:

"Your mobile phone has been successfully verified."

But it still tells me I have to be verified every time.  Googling has not helped, and facebook doesn't seem to have any support for matters like this, **except they said they hang out on stackoverflow a lot.**  I tried to join the facebook developer group, but I haven't heard back.  So I'm hoping someone here knows something.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

They've replied to me in the past there

Comment: Yes; I've tried that, but how do I contact someone from that page?  They say to join the developers group, but that's closed and I'm still "pending."

Comment: If you can, file a bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs